# Two CFwheels apps are mixing their configurations

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I am working on an existing project that someone else started and I am having some really weird issues.

This is the rundown:

We had a cfwheels app running under test.com/admin and we wanted to make it a stand alone app to run under admin.test.com.
The developer who was in charge of the project copied the contents of the admin folder (the entire wheels app) and dumped them in a new folder. He also created a new site in IIS and mapped the physical path to run from the correct folder.

The problem now is this, when one app is running the other one is throwing an error which is telling me that the admin.test.com is pulling the contents of test.com/admin. Now if I do a reload=true and run the new application first, the new app is working and the old one is throwing an error.....

I know that this sounds a bit confusing but does anyone have an idea where to look and what I might need to change to make this issue go away?

Comment: Make sure the application names are not the same.

Comment: Inside the config/app.cfm ?

Comment: The root Application.cfc/cfm for each site.

Comment: Is your answer based on cfwheels or straight up CF? Because the Application.cfc file in cfwheels doesn't have anything like this inside. The name is declared in app.cfm under config/

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno your solution worked. Please add it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `application.name` values are the same for both applications, then whichever runs first, configures them both.

Comment: As a note, the application name in CFWheels is declared inside config/app.cfm Thanks Andrian